# Apache Reverse Proxy breaks on application logout

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse

My apache knowledge is quite limited.  I've been asked to set up a reverse proxy at my work place.  The webapp is on a windows server/ IIS.  our reverse proxy is apache on Solaris.

Here's my issue.  the reverse proxy works fine, until you log out of the webapp. I have little exposure to the webapp as it's vendor purchased code.  The behaviour is as follows.

login at external-url.com/ all works fine. Traverse the application no problems, but once the log out button is pressed, the sign in page is redirected to the server being proxied

The vendor claims this isn't an issue with their logout method.  when I log into the webapp directly on the internalServer using the IP address, at logout I am not redirected to the server alias, but rather I'm presented the logout page with the IP address still in the url.

So at some point in the log out process the url is re-written for the end user from the externally accessible url to the internal server.

I hope I explained this in an understandable way.

here's my setting in the apache virtual host

```
ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
         #Allow from all
         Allow from .ourdomain.com
    </Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://crdpcenter01.ourdomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://crdpcenter01.ourdomain.com/
```